# Receiving UDP Unicast Video Stream on Windows CE

Tags: c#, video, compact-framework, windows-ce, directshow

I'm not strictly a software developer, I'm an electronic engineer and I mainly deal with hardware and C on micros, but I've just inherited a C# project that needs a slight tweak making to it (at least I hope it's slight!). I've done a fair bit with C# on the full and compact framework, but I have no experience when it comes to DirectShow.

We have a Windows CE 6.0 device, and it runs some C# software for a digital signage type product. Part of the display can be configured as a video, and it can currently play files stored locally on the device's SD card without much issue. I've been asked to make it work with a UDP network stream (I believe it will be RAW MPEG4, I'm just waiting on final confirmation).

From reading up on this, I'm aware that DirectShow uses "filters", and that there are source, decoder and render filters. They connect together via "pins", and form a "filter graph". I see that DirectShow is all COM based, and while I'm aware of COM, I've never actually used it in anger myself. I do have this C# software that I've inherited though, so I'm not starting from a blank canvas.

I believe the section I need to look at modifying is this:

```
clsid = CLSID_.FilterGraph;
riid = IID_.ICaptuGraphBuilder2;
hr = (HRESULT)PInvokes.CoCreateInstance(ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)CLSCTX_.INPROC_SERVER, riid, out obj);
_graphBuilder = (IGraphBuilder)obj;

hr = (HRESULT)_graphBuilder.RenderFile(filePath, null);
```

According to the article at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834433.aspx and various other sources, Windows CE supports:

- MMS streaming
- HTTP streaming
- File streaming
- Broadcast and Multi Bit Rate Streaming
- Windows Media Station support
- ASX support
- Codecs

Now, am I right in thinking that Windows CE doesn't natively support streaming from UDP? If so, I have a few questions:

1. I've read that it's possible to create custom DirectShow filters. My technical ability aside, would this be an option for achieving what I want here? I've found http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/dshowfilter , but I'm not very familiar with C++ and I'm having trouble getting it into VS2008 to play about with it. I'm fairly proficient with C and C#, so I'm hoping that for something like this I should be able to fumble my way through if I have to?
2. Is anyone aware of any existing component out there that will do what I want already? Something that we can purchase? I cant afford to throw too much time at this. I've done a little searching about for "Windows CE DirectShow" and "Windows CE DirectShow source filters" but I just get the same few articles and unanswered forum posts. I'm not sure if nothing exists, or I'm searching for the wrong thing?
3. If I do write this myself, I've found articles such as [this](http://www.sichbo.ca/Free_Code/100_C_Sharp_directshow_filters), where they've created filters in C# rather than C++. This looks a little more in my comfort zone, but I'm still not sure of what I need to do exactly. I'm fine with the idea of getting the UDP stream data in, but I'm not sure what I need to do with it next to get it to the "output pin". And how do I modify our software to use this custom filter as opposed to a normal filter? Just generally getting started with an empty source filter seems beyond me at the moment!

I'm sorry if some of this seems like trivial stuff, but its all been a bit too much to take in in one go, and I just need a bit of guidance I think. I'd be massively appreciative if anyone could help me out!

Thanks in advance,

Rik

Answer (score 3):

As to your questions:

1. Yes, a custom Direct Show filter is exactly what you need.  That filter could then be plugged into your filtergraph.
2. I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf products for Windows CE that would do this, but I've never looked for one either so don't assume my lack of knowledge equals lack of availability.  My bet is that if you want to base your work off of someone else's, you're going to have to find a desktop version of the filter, get the source, then recompile it for Windows CE.  I know that [LEADTOOLS](http://www.leadtools.com) has a boatload of imaging stuff, so it's probably worth at least an inquiry there.
3. If you write it yourself it's, unfortunately, got to be done in C++.  DirectShow filters *must* have a COM interface.  To export a native interface, a framework must have EE Hosting, which the Compact Framework does not.  The net result of that is that you cannot create COM objects or CCW's in the Compact Framework, meaning you can't create a DirectShow filter in C# for Windows CE.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I've got the ball filter sample up and running on my desktop. I'm thinking of modifying it to take in the data from the UDP source and then porting it over to WinCE.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to purchase a product, I'd suggest contacting [Chris Tacke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13154/ctacke) to see if his company has something or can do something.

His blog is [>> HERE <<](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/default.aspx). I think he's about the biggest authority on Compact Framework development to go to for real questions.

I do not, however, see any way to contact him on his blog. Maybe he will change that in the near future.

Comment: Ah, but my email address is in my SO profile that you've linked.  Putting it in my blog, which I had done in the past, leads to an amazing volume of spam (well amazingly more than I already get).